# Is the string "Hello\0" equal to {'H','e','l','l','o','\0'} or {'H','e','l','l','o','\0'}?

Tags: c++, c, string

Is the string `"Hello\n"` equal to
`{'H','e','l','l','o','\','n','\0'}`  or
`{'H','e','l','l','o','\n','\0'}`?

Does adding escape sequences in string definitions like:

```
char arr[] = "Hello\n";
```

Create strings like:

```
char arr[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\','n','\0'};
```

or strings like:

```
char arr[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\n','\0'};
```

also is the NULL character '\0' added every time when a declaration like `char* foo = "HelloWorld!"`  is used.

Comment: You can check by printing each character's numeric value separately (or looking in a debugger).

Comment: **Second**. String `"Hello\\n"` is equal to the first

Comment: `'\'` is not a valid piece of C++ code.

Comment: your title makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @n.m. sure it is!  Just not a character literal.  `"'\'"` see?  And not valid where the OP wrote it.

Comment: I'd write it as `constexpr auto arr{"Hello\n"};`

Comment: Title and question differ.  Is it "Hello\0" or "Hello\n"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second interpretation is correct, since the escape sequence you are talking about (newline), is only 1 character in length. The NULL character *is* added to to the end every time you make such a declaration.

The reason your first interpretation is incorrect, is because \ is the escape character, meaning it would escape the quote right after it. You can even see this in Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting!

```
char arr[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\','n',\0'};
//  See how the n is not highlighted --^
```

As evident, the `n` is outside the quotes and is interpreted as a keyword or an identifier.

Answer (score 5):

`"Hello\n"` means `{'H','e','l','l','o','\n','\0'}`. It's `\n` is the newline character.

```
char* foo = "HelloWorld!"
```

is assigning the decayed pointer to the literal `char` array to the `char*` `foo`. And yes that string literal is `null` terminated char array.

Note that `char* foo = ...` and `char foo[]=".."` are two different things. The second one initializes the char array `foo` with the content of the string literal. First one is simply pointing to the immutable literal string(`foo` is pointing to that literal string).

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) 6.7.9

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. *Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the elements of the array*.

If you compiled your code with `char arr[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\','n',\0'};` you will likely to see the message

```
error: stray '\' in program
```

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1) 5.2.1 again:

> *In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by escape sequences consisting of **the backslash `\` followed by one or more characters***. A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.